# dataGrid doesn't display the image

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a dataGrid which display a list of persons.

The problem is that the dataGrid doesn't display the image a person it's diplayed like this :

```
System.Byte[].
```

Comment: Win or web? Win - add a control that knows how to show an image. Web - Add an img tag and set the url.

Comment: it's Win .. But how can I do that ?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/c17ee134-0021-49ec-ab6b-37adbb2ff58b/

Comment: that's answer you gived me it's by usign it's path but i'm using a picture that's already in a dataBase

Comment: This is just a sample. You can get the image bytes from database and set them as the value of each cell. Try to look for samples of image in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Http Handler(.ashx) where you can write the code to display the image using Response header and then use that handler like below to display the image

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">     
        <ItemTemplate>         
             <img src="displayImage.ashx?id=111"  style="text-align:center"/> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I'm using Win apllication not web application